# Dexie not store data in production build, but all works normally in dev build

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex, dexie

I wrote an app based on Vue v2 and Vuex that uses Dexie as data access layer to IndexedDB. Over Dexie, i put another layer that use Repository pattern to manage the creation and persistence of entity instances. All works fine while use dev-server of vue-cli. And also works fine when i build a dev version of the app. But when i build for production, the app initializes correctly, Dexie creates de DB based on defined schema, but don't writes any data to db. Because of that, the app fails when try to read data that's not in there.

Finally, Dexie don't throw any error that help me to know what's going on.

The app code it's very large, so before to write an small example to reproduce de error, i asking here if someone faces the same problem of mine.

Many thx in advance.

Comment: Atleast you should add some sort of build scripts or config

Comment: I run the vue-cli "npm run build" command with the default config. Those are available to anyone that uses vue-cli. It's necessary post the config that vue-cli generates?

Answer (score 0):

Is the production build served from a different origin? Maybe there is an already existing database with the same name at that origin that had other primary keys configured in its schema, or is on same or later version and therefore could not be upgraded.

Things you could try:

1. Upgrade to dexie@latest `npm i dexie@latest` (or dexie@next) which may give better warnings on existing incompatible schema than older versions.
2. Catch the promise returned by db.open() and log it. It may reveal important information about why the DB couldn't be opened.
3. Give the DB a different name in Dexie constructor, or else delete it using devtools prior to refreshing the page.